# How to update all references on Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press control+right click on visual studio code I can see a list where a function is called/referenced (same as right click->go to references). However this list sometimes is not updated . Is there a way to automatically update all references on visual studio code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug/defect.. A workaround is to copy the term you are noticing this behavior about, paste it on the search area and press enter. The references will be automatically updated.